# How to handle onServiceConnected after onPause?

Tags: android, service

When binding a service `onServiceConnected` is called asynchronously As far as I can tell, it is possible that the activity that bound the service might be paused before the service is connected. How should this situation be handled in terms of `unbindService`?

`unbindService` requires a reference to the ServiceConnection, which was passed to `bindService` so it can be called immediately after `bindService`. Are there any ordering issues? In general I don't believe Android has many guarantees for the execution order of asynchronous calls.